# How do you add a $ in front of the value for the y-axis using ngx-charts

Tags: angular, typescript, graph, bar-chart, ngx-charts

I have a question related to Angular and TypeScript, using https://swimlane.gitbooks.io/ngx-charts/content/charts/bar-vertical.html I am trying to let the y-axis to be = $100, $200, $300 but if I set $ + a number it returns an error `Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,NaNhNaNhNaNv…".`

It looks like the value for the object must be a number! But I want a $ + number. How do I go about this?

This is what I current have this.

```
let modifiedBarGraphValues = [
{
    'name': 'sun',
    'value': 100,
  },
{
    'name': 'sun',
    'value': 200,
}, ];
```

modifiedBarGraphValues[i].value = this.amountObtained(weekEarnings[j], payRate);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `yAxisTickFormatting` function for this. Inside your htmls `ngx-charts-bar-vertical`, add

```
[yAxisTickFormatting]="myYAxisTickFormatting"
```

Then inside your component, you would implement the function like so:

```
myYAxisTickFormatting(val) {
    return '$' + val;
}
```

Comment: person of the year! Thank you so much!

Comment: It messed up the layout of the graphs, the y-axis is now a lot longer than it was before, but this was very helpful! How do I mark your solution accepted?

Comment: Okay, no I accidentally deleted the x-axis label which is why it showed all messed up. Thank you so much this answer worked like a charm